# aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’

Tags: op-tee, rockchip

I'm collecting tee.bin for aarm64 rockchip-rk3399. Set the environment variable: compiler, platform. But during assembly it complains about errors.  https://optee.readthedocs.io  
Download the code for build. Installed the environment 
`cd /opt` 
`git clone https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os.git` 
`cd ./optee_os` 
`user@ubuntu#export` 
`declare -x CFG_TEE_CORE_LOG_LEVEL="4"` 
`declare -x CROSS_COMPILE="/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-"` 
`declare -x PATH="/usr/lib/:/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-     gnu/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"` 
`declare -x PLATFORM="rockchip-rk3399"` 
Start the build 
`user@ubuntu# make`
..... 
`CHK     out/arm-plat-rockchip/conf.mk` 
`CHK     out/arm-plat-rockchip/include/generated/conf.h` 
`CHK     out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/include/generated/asm-defines.h`
`CC      out/arm-plat-rockchip/ta_arm32-lib/libdl/dlfcn.o`
`aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthumb’` 
`aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-unaligned-access’; did you mean ‘-Wno-aligned-new’?`
`aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfloat-abi=hard’`
`make: *** [mk/compile.mk:165: out/arm-plat-rockchip/ta_arm32-lib/libdl/dlfcn.o] Error 1`
Run build install custom CROSS_COMPILE 
`make CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin` 
 
3min build and error 
`OBJDUMP out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/tee.dmp`
`GEN     out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/tee.bin`
`GEN     out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/tee-header_v2.bin`
`GEN     out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/tee-pager_v2.bin`
`GEN     out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/tee-pageable_v2.bin`
`GEN     out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/tee.symb_sizes`
`GEN     out/arm-plat-rockchip/core/tee-raw.bin`
`OBJDUMP out/arm-plat-rockchip/ldelf/ldelf.dmp`
`CC      out/arm-plat-rockchip/ta_arm32-lib/libdl/dlfcn.o`
`bash: line 1: /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bingcc: No such file or directory`
`make: *** [mk/compile.mk:165: out/arm-plat-rockchip/ta_arm32-lib/libdl/dlfcn.o] Error 127`

Answer (score 1):

compiled successfully using the clang-12.0.0 compiler

Comment: nice one - well done

Answer (score 0):

It could be a missing dependency, maybe try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` first.

Comment: Completed. But it did not help.

Comment: It seens to have trouble finding the gnu compiler shown in the error here - 'bash: line 1: /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bingcc: No such file or directory' try doublechecking the compiler location and any MIME extensions needed for explictness maybe. Maybe find another way to execute the compiler and check your syntax - sorry I've not ever installed op tee so i'm unable to help much further. I wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume something is missing here.  The '-m..' errors could be missing maths dependencies. gcc - am I right in thinking that is the gnu c++ compiler? Maybe the compiler lacks a library? You can try adding `-lm` to the end of your gcc command to include the maths library.

Comment: compiled successfully using the clang-12.0.0 compiler